# I need a C program that plots a horizontal graph of sin x/x from -4pi to 4pi in text mode

Tags: c, graph

How to draw a horizontal graph of sin x/x (-4pi to 4pi) in text mode in C language?

Comment: Firstly you have to think how to express a graph in text mode. How will a graph of x/(4pi) (4pi to -4pi) look like, for example?

Comment: At least your program does not contain any errors, unless I miss something.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yes it compiles without any warnings.

Comment: Seriously, Souvik, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not particularly well suited for this site. For example, it does not contain any code. That in itself is frowned upon: This is, after all, a programming site. It also does not ask a specific technical question; instead, you are asking us to do your homework. Homework questions are OK, but you need to show an effort (with code, as said above) and ask about specific problems that you have trouble with. See for example [this discussion.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3150802).

Comment: So you can make an own effort first and then, if you have specific problems (which can be very basic!) edit the question, provide details etc.

Comment: I think a _horizontal graph_ rather goes like this:
```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int w = 80; /* use horizontal width 80 \*/
    for (float x = -4*M_PI; x <= 4*M_PI; ++x)
        printf("%*c\n", (int)((sin(x)/x+.22)/1.22*w), '*');
}
```
min{sin(x)/x} ≈ -0.217234  
max{sin(x)/x} = 1

Comment: You may want to read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Answer (score 3):

So, given your general problem description, here is a tongue-in-cheek solution. It stands on the shoulders of giants, assuming the [gnuplot utility](http://www.gnuplot.info/) in the path. `pi` is a predefined variable in gnuplot with the value one would assume:

```
$ cat plot.c && gcc -o plot plot.c && ./plot
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("echo \"set terminal dumb; set xrange [-4*pi:4*pi]; plot sin(x)/x\" | gnuplot");
}



    1 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
      |      +             +           * +*           +             +      |
      |                               *    *              sin(x)/x ******* |
  0.8 |-+                            *      *                            +-|
      |                              *      *                              |
      |                              *       *                             |
  0.6 |-+                           *        *                           +-|
      |                            *          *                            |
      |                            *          *                            |
  0.4 |-+                          *          *                          +-|
      |                           *            *                           |
  0.2 |-+                         *             *                        +-|
      |            *             *              *             *            |
      |         *******         *                *         *******         |
    0 |-+     ***      *        *                *        *      ***     +-|
      |***  ***         *      *                  *      *         ***  ***|
      |   ***            **   *                    *   **            ***   |
 -0.2 |-+                 *****                    *****                 +-|
      |                                                                    |
      |      +             +             +            +             +      |
 -0.4 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
            -10           -5             0            5             10
```

Comment: I've used gnuplot for 20 years, but never to a dumb terminal -- nice trick.